# How do I use emailVerified from AngularFire2 to redirect a user whose email in not verified?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm unable to find an example for using emailVerified AngularFire2 exported pipe to redirect a user whose email is not yet verified from specific routes.

Use cases on how to use redirectLoggedInTo(redirect), redirectUnauthorizedTo(redirect) and hasCustomClaim(claim) are provided.

The AngularFire team has conveniently avoided putting an example on their GitHub page here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code `emailVerified` is:

```js
export const emailVerified: AuthPipe = map(user => !!user && user.emailVerified)
```

So you can use a second `map` like this:

```js
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, emailVerified } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

...

const redirectUnverifiedUser = () =>
  pipe(
    emailVerified,
    map(emailVerified => {
      if (emailVerified) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return ['login', 'verify-email']
      }
    })
  );
```

...and then in your route config:

```js
{
  path: 'example',
  ...
  canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
  data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnverifiedUser },
},
```

---

If you need to redirect an **unauthorized** user to your login page but also redirect an **authorized** user who has not verified their email to a different page then you can use this:

```js
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, AuthPipeGenerator } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

...

const redirectUnauthorizedOrUnverifiedUser: AuthPipeGenerator = () =>
  map(user => {
    if (user) {
      if (user.emailVerified) {
        return true
      } else {
        return ['login', 'verify-email']
      }
    } else {
      return ['login']
    }
  })
```

...and then in your route config:

```js
{
  path: 'example',
  ...
  canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
  data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedOrUnverifiedUser },
},
```

Comment: Can you answer my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575931/how-to-use-angularfire-redirectunauthorizedto-to-redirect-unauthorized-users-b  

FYI, your answer is out of date. `AngularFireAuthGuard` is no longer an exported member of module `'@angular/fire/auth-guard'`.