# How to make an AngularFire route guard that redirects unauthorized users back to landing page?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

This route guard blocks unauthorized access to `my-project.com/home` but it redirects users to a blank page, not to my landing page.

`app-routing.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthPipe, AuthGuard, AuthGuardModule, AuthPipeGenerator, canActivate, hasCustomClaim, idTokenResult, isNotAnonymous, loggedIn, redirectLoggedInTo, redirectUnauthorizedTo, customClaims, emailVerified, } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

// components
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'default', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedTo(['landing']) }}, // route guard is here
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    AuthGuardModule,
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This route didn't compile:

```js
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate(() => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['/landing'])) },
```

That threw this error message:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Type '{ path: string; component: typeof HomeComponent; canActivate(): any; }' has no call signatures.
```

I tried `AuthPipe` and `AuthPipeGenerator` instead of `authGuardPipe` (which isn't a method of `'@angular/fire/auth-guard'`).

I imported Auth and Auth-Guard into `app.module.ts` but that didn't help.

```js
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { provideAuth, getAuth, } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthGuardModule } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    AuthGuardModule,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing

```js
const redirectUnauthorizedToLanding = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['landing']);
```

Now my code works.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard, redirectUnauthorizedTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

// components
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const redirectUnauthorizedToLanding = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['landing']); // this was missing

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'default', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLanding }},
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

No need to import `'@angular/fire/auth'` into `app-routing.module.ts`.

No need to import `'@angular/fire/auth-guard'` into `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Can you post your add.module code please?